# Woocommerce Get Product Description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm Trying to get the product description next to product name which will be sent in one of the woocommerce emails so i found 2 ways & i don't know the difference between them and which one is the right one.

1st Solution

```
$item_data ['description'] = $product->get_name() . " - " . $product->get_description();
```

2nd Solution

```
$item_data ['description'] = $product->get_name() . " -" . wp_strip_all_tags($product->get_description());
```

What is the difference between both solutions and which is the better way & why ?

Best Regards

Comment: Both way is write. but in 2nd solution all the tags of the html is remove. direct description without any html tags. so selection of the solution is depend on your needs.

Comment: Which means both can be used for the woocommerce right ? Without any limitations

Comment: yes. both are used for woo-commerce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This differs from  wp_strip_all_tags() because it removes the contents of the  and  tags. E.g. strip_tags( 'something' ) will return ‘something’. wp_strip_all_tags will return ”

Comment: Didn't get it, can you apply it on my situation ?